# Get ordered list of middleware in a generic rack application?

Tags: ruby, rake, rack, middleware

The functionality I am looking for is similar to the `rake middleware` command in Rails, except for a generic rack application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will return a list of all the middleware for a rack application:

```
def middleware_classes(app)
  app.instance_variable_get(:@use).map{|middleware| middleware.call.class.name }
end

app = Rack::Builder.parse_file('config.ru').first; nil # trailing nil to avoid paging in an interactive console
p middleware_classes(app)
```

Comment: +1 worked like a charm. I put all of this into a `test-rack.rb` script and ran it via `ruby test-rack.rb`. (edited question to add missing rack require ;)

Answer (score 46):

```
$ rake middleware

use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007ffd148f9468>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
run RackTest::Application.routes
```

http://pothibo.com/2013/11/ruby-on-rails-inside-actiondispatch-and-rack/

Comment: From the description, it's clear he knows about `rake middleware`. He wants this for a non-Rails app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Sinatra app that extends `Sinatra::Base`, I had to use a slightly modified version of Michael Hale's answer:

```rb
require 'rack'
​
def middleware_classes(app)
  r = [app]
  ​
  while ((next_app = r.last.instance_variable_get(:@app)) != nil)
    r << next_app
  end
  ​
  r.map{|e| e.instance_variable_defined?(:@app) ? e.class : e }
end
​
sinatra_app = Rack::Builder.parse_file('config.ru').first
sinatra_rack_builder = sinatra_app.build(sinatra_app)
sinatra_extended_app = sinatra_rack_builder.to_app
rack_app = sinatra_extended_app.app

pp middleware_classes(rack_app)
```

​
After putting this into a file such as `dump_middleware.rb` I was able to see the middleware as expected:

```
$ bundle exec ruby ./dump_middleware.rb
[Rack::Head,
 Rack::NullLogger,
 Rack::Session::Cookie,
 Rack::Protection::FrameOptions,
 Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin,
 Rack::Protection::IPSpoofing,
 Rack::Protection::JsonCsrf,
 Rack::Protection::PathTraversal,
 Rack::Protection::RemoteToken,
 Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking,
 Rack::Protection::XSSHeader,
 Warden::Manager,
 SinatraApp]
```

There might be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [rack-graph](https://github.com/rkh/rack-graph) by Konstantin Haase.

For some reason, Konstantin has not seen fit to bundle it as a gem, so you will need to install it using git and reference it locally.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rkh/rack-graph.git
$ ruby -I/path/to/rack-graph/lib $(which rackup) -s Graph
```

Given the following example Rack application:

```
# config.ru
Foo = proc { [200, {}, ['Foo']] }
App = proc { [200, {}, ['Ok']] }

map '/foo' do
  use Rack::Runtime
  use Rack::MethodOverride
  run Foo
end

run App
```

This is the output:

```
# Output:
Rack::ContentLength
 |- Rack::CommonLogger(stderr)
    |- Rack::ShowExceptions
       |- Rack::Lint
          |- Rack::TempfileReaper
             |- Rack::URLMap
                |- "/foo"
                |  |- Rack::Runtime
                |     |- Rack::MethodOverride
                |        |- Proc(0x00007fd93a97c2d0 /Users/steve/ruby/config.ru:1)
                |
                |- ""
                   |- Proc(0x00007fd93a97c2a8 /Users/steve/ruby/config.ru:2)
```

Comment: Bundler install version does not work: Could not find gem 'rack-graph' in https://github.com/rkh/rack-graph.git (at master@aa669c0). The library is so raw that it isn't packaged as a gem at all.  (no gemspec!)

Comment: @PeterH.Boling Ah, you're right.  I've removed references to it being a gem.

Answer (score -3):

this is long overdue, I know

[here's a nice thread](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CBIQFjAAOAo&url=http://groups.google.com/group/sinatrarb/browse_thread/thread/312e1d3f190cf234&ei=C_hYTtXDE8iCOqDZrY0M&usg=AFQjCNGScVg49MiofJPoMp_ZONAyqShWoQ&sig2=WybVjCa9mgKAbHlyVaYBLw), the definitive answer is the last post

UPDATED as per Marc-Andre's comment:

The following is the last post from this [link](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CBIQFjAAOAo&url=http://groups.google.com/group/sinatrarb/browse_thread/thread/312e1d3f190cf234&ei=C_hYTtXDE8iCOqDZrY0M&usg=AFQjCNGScVg49MiofJPoMp_ZONAyqShWoQ&sig2=WybVjCa9mgKAbHlyVaYBLw)

Rack does not have a mechanism for that and since not all middleware is added via @middleware, Sinatra can't tell you what middleware is used. Neither can rails, btw, it can just tell you what is possible. Middleware does not have to be a linear list (i.e. when using a Rack router or something).

Comment: -1. The whole point of SO is not to have to go through list of postings. Copy & improve the right answer and add that link as a source.